# SocketChannel read() behaviour - short reads

Tags: java, nio, java-7

The `ServerSocketChannel` is used this way:

```
ServerSocketChannel srv = ServerSocketChannel.open();
srv.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(8112));
SocketChannel client = srv.accept();
```

When a connection is received, data is read this way:

```
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(2000);
data.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
client.read(data);
logger.debug("Position: {} bytes read!", data.position());
```

It prints:

> Position: 16 bytes read!

Why isn't the SocketChannel blocking until the buffer is filled?
From the `ServerSocketChannel.accept()` API (Java 7):

> The socket channel returned by this method, if any, will be in
>   blocking mode regardless of the blocking mode of this channel.

Does the `write(ByteBuffer buffer)` of the SocketChannel block? How do I test that anyway?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocking mode means that it blocks until *any* data is received. It doesn't have to be an entire buffer full.

If you want to make sure you've received an entire bufferful of data, you should `read()` in a loop until you've filled up your buffer.

Comment: What happens on write(ByteBuffer buffer) operations?

Comment: Also, can anyone explain which Use Case returns 0 for a read(...) or write(...) ? If it keeps reading 0 bytes, I might want to put some sleep(10) at some point. But before I do that, I want to understand. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBourgeois A blocking mode write will block until all data has been transferred. A non-blocking write may transfer zero or more bytes. Only a non-blocking read can return zero, meaning no data is present. It is used in conjunction with Selector and OP_READ.

Comment: @EJP: So for the 'write' I can drop the loop (and make sure it's blocking). For the read I can drop the sleep(), as the loop won't keep returning me 0 when reading. Awesome, thanks a lot (to both of you!) !